# Error while trying to implement a periodic message on a Telegram Bot with Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I'm trying to implement a Telegram Bot function that allows my account to periodically receive an update message, but I receive this error when I execute the function:

> telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API
> was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated
> by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is
> running

This is my code.

```
import threading

import telebot
import Consts

from mypackage.ProcessManager import ProcessManager


bot = telebot.TeleBot(Consts.bot_token, threaded=True)
process_manager = ProcessManager()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
def subscribe(message):
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    if not process_manager.has_running_elements(chat_id):
        process_manager.start_process(chat_id=chat_id,
                                  target=send_message,
                                  arg2=chat_id, arg3="Prova")
        bot.reply_to(message, "Perfetto. Da ora riceverai aggiornamenti sulla tua assicurazione")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Sei già iscritto")


def send_message(chat_id, message: str):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

ProcessManager is just a wrapper class that handles multiprocessing.Process objects. I'm also sharing that start_process function:

```
    def start_process(self, chat_id, target, **args):
        new_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=target,
                                          daemon=True,
                                          args=args)
        self.processes_dict[chat_id] = new_process
        new_process.start()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ You're using multiprocessing to make multiple bot instances, which is not allowed.  Telegram only allows one bot to be signed in to your account at a time.

Comment: My intent is to use multiprocessing to make multiple calls to send_message function, which uses always the same bot instance. I don't understand how I am creating multiple bot instances..

Comment: You're making a whole new process.  You can't possibly be using "the same bot instance".

Comment: Do you know what could I change? I see from the exception that my code is generating multiple instances of the bot, but I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: Can you explain why you are even using multiprocessing?  Is there some speed or performance issue that you thought multiprocessing would solve?

Comment: It's not about speed. I thought that, by creating a parallel process, I could handle multiple subscription by different accounts.

Comment: Multiprocessing makes more copies of **this exact program**, so obviously they would all be using the same bot account.  I don't understand how you expected this to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255847/discussion-between-fabrizio-gabriele-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it using multithreading.Thread instead of multiprocessing.Process.